# Stream a video file using RTMP protocol to an rtmp server using Python

Tags: python, nginx, streaming, rtmp

can anyone guide me to do the mentioned above?
basically what i want:

A python script that will stream a single video file to an RTMP Server (in my case nginx), to the link:

```
rtmp://<ip>/stream/<stream_name>
```

So, ideally the video file will be streamed with a `<Stream_name>`. Next i want this stream_name to be generated in a series, for example: `stream_1, stream_2,....stream_n`. Then i would want the stream link: `rtmp://<ip>/stream/<stream_name>` **being pushed n times**, **but in each iteration, the stream name is incremented from "stream_1" to "stream_2" and so on**.

I am currently struggling to find the right library to do this in python.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @NeelDutta are u able to stream video on RTMP server? if yes can you please let me know which python lib u have used ?

Comment: Not python, but in bash I've been doing this with `ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i /PATH/TO/VIDEO.MP4 -b:v 50M -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/` (where you can swap in your own rtmp server url)

Answer (score 3):

The key in here is FFMpeg. Use any suitable wrapper of FFMpeg based on your needs.
Here is the first one in Google: 
https://pypi.org/project/python-ffmpeg-video-streaming/

Comment: Yup I  realized it after posting it!  Anyways got my job done by using a python script to simulate multiple ffmpeg instances